# Search in whole xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I whant to create a function that return `True` if a specified string is in the xml document. The problem is that i need to search in the whole document and not a specifide element, and the xml can contain severals levels... how can i do that?

Comment: You should provide more details. What are you looking for. Just a string? A string in a specific node?

Comment: Do you want to search everything or just the element values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Treat the contents of the XML as a string, and just search the content string for the one you are looking for.

```
public bool FileContainsString(string filePath, string searchString)
{
    string fileContents;
    using(FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(reader))
    {
        fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return fileContents.Contains(searchString);
}
```

This code was not tested

If you want a case-insensitive search for the string, replace

```
    return fileContents.Contains(searchString);
```

with

```
    return fileContents.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

Comment: "String to search for" should be a parameter, don't you think? Reuse, reuse, reuse...

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc;
bool contains = doc.InnerXml.IndexOf("Your text") != -1
```

should do the trick, but it will find the text even if it is contained in a tag, if you want just to check for plain text use:

```
XmlDocument doc;
    bool contains = doc.InnerText.IndexOf("Your text") != -1
```